# Can I use App Service Storage to make files dynamically generated permanently downloadable by the public or do I need to use Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

It was recommended to me to use Azure Storage instead of the storage that comes with the App Service to store some text files created by the app that are downloadable be people. The text files will be permanently available once created. The reason was there may be issues with the text files across app instances. I was reading this is only an issue for temp space and that the app storage in home/wwwroot was persistent across app instances. This leads me to believe it will be ok to use that storage to store generated text files for download.

If the text files are not stored in a temp space and in the persistent app space is Azure storage still recommended? And if so how can I mount or access the storage in such a way that the files are downloadable via a direct link?

Comment: What happens when you delete your app service? All the files will be deleted. It would be better to store them in Azure Storage.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this way of doing things and line of thinking so forgive me if ask a n obvious question. Why would be a situation where I would delete my app service? And if there was a situation couldn't I download the data before deleting to back it up?

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question and wants to clarify a few points:

1) There are two types of app service storage

2) Persistent (d:\home) and temporary (clean up restart) and it seems you're aware of it.

3) also the storage capacity comes with the app service plan tier and the number of application hosted on that app service plan whereas temp storage is per-app service.

4) Now think of the situation if you're web app got deleted and Azure has some mechanism to restore the deleted web app using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-undelete provided the deleted app service must be running on a Basic or above pricing tier plan at the time of deletion to restore it.

Please make a note this undelete uses a snapshot feature of app service architecture describe at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-restore-snapshots.

The file system of azure app service is described here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure

Conclusion:
To use the Azure storage account with soft delete enabled to protect from such accident and have data back with you always.

I hope it clarifies your concerns and helps in understanding the why azure storage to use.

Comment: Can you please tell me the logic that lead you to your conclusion?

Comment: Hi Aztek,
When you use azure storage you're no longer depends on azure app service for data back up. Please note that even if you use app services back up it ask for storage account such that application content stored at that location and can be used where ever you want.